# Uninstalling Window and using Ubuntu as the only OS

Tags: 14.04, grub2, windows-8, filesystem, software-uninstall

I do all my task in Ubuntu. How will I be able to ***remove the Windows8 using ubuntu?*** **I don't want to see Windows8 name displayed  in the grub menu**. And I want **Ubuntu to be started in the first hand after I boot my computer**. *Will it harm any files, folder and partition?*

Comment: open gparted utility. and remove the partation used by windows. And no it will not harm your current OS.

Comment: It is required to specify how Ubuntu is installed? alongside or not?

Comment: you should first delete the windows 8 partition using gparted and then allocate the unallocated space created

Comment: Dishank failed to ask if the Windows partition is the first or second partition on the drive. He also didn't mention that you'll need to do this from a live cd or usb, and not from your current Ubuntu install. If Windows is on the first partition, deleting it and expanding Ubuntu back into the space Windows once took up does have the potential for data loss and to break your current install. Expect it to take forever (4 or 5 hrs minimum) Back up your files before doing anything, and maybe consider just doing a fresh install and restoring your files to that. It'll be a hell of a lot faster.

Comment: @Pandya What other way of Ubuntu being installed are you thinking might apply to a system that has both Ubuntu and Windows 8 installed? An unsupported Wubi installation? Separate hard disks? I suppose either of these or other configurations are possible. But I don't think your comment makes clear what information you're looking for. In particular, I don't think manual vs. automatic partitioning (during installation) makes a difference here.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways of doing this.

1. While installing select erase everything and install Ubuntu as only OS. (First option)
2. Install Ubuntu alongside Windows or create separate partitions and install Ubuntu. After installing use the software grub-customizer and delete Windows entry there. Then you can manually delete Windows files.